# What is "Client Isolation" called on wired networks?

Tags: ethernet

Wireless AP's commonly support a "Client Isolation" option to prevent wireless clients from communicating with each other.

Is this feature commonly supported on wired ethernet switches to prevent wired clients from seeing or communicating with each other? What is it called? Is this an advanced feature that's typically only available on "enterprise grade" switches, or can it be found in low-end Layer 3 managed switches as well?

Comment: Layer 3 switches commonly support Virtual Local Area Networks (VLAN)

Comment: Sure, VLAN's would do what I want, but I'd have to create a VLAN for every user with their own unique IP ranges, DHCP bindings, etc, I assumed switches these days could do this type of isolation automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common term for port isolation on wired networks is *[Private VLAN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_VLAN)*.

However the term "port isolation" seems to be increasing in popularity with the rise of all-wireless client accesss networks, even when referring to wired networks. The "Private VLAN" term originated with Cisco, at a time when they had massive market share. That has changed in recent years as Cisco per-port market share has declined and networking has become more commodiized.